# Why don't p-type seismic waves propagate along straight lines in the lower mantle?

Tags: waves, refraction, geophysics, earthquake

Can you tell me why seismic waves (p-type shock wave) passing through the earth's lower mantle don't propagate along straight lines in particular?

Comment: Did you try anything to figure this out yourself, like a web search or checking references?

Answer (score 0):

The density and modulus of the Earth changes with depth (as Earth is hotter inside), and this affects the speed of propagation. Just as light refracts when it encounters a change in refractive index, you can think of this change in speed of propagation to change the "refractive index of pressure waves".